# getting child of child in eloquent relations

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-blade

I'm new to laravel relations and eloquent and I have the following three models and I want to get the num_rooms by using a reservation object inside my blade view which , I tried the below code but it didn't work and I got an error :

"Trying to get property 'rtypes' of non-object"

how can I achieve this ?? and thank you in advance

```
@foreach($reservations as $reservation)

           <p>{{$reservation->rdates->first()->rtypes->first()->num_rooms}}</p><br>

@endforeach
```

Reservation model:

```
    <?php


    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Reservation extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'reservations';


    protected $dates = [
        'canceled_at'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'canceled_at',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by'
    ];
  

    public function rdates(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\RDate','reservation_id','id');
    }
   }
```

rdate model:

```
<?php


namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class RDate extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'r_dates';

    protected $casts = [
        'reservation_id' => 'int'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'date'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'reservation_id',
        'date',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by'
    ];

    public function rtypes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rtype','r_date_id','id');
    }

    public function reservations(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Reservation','reservation_id','id');
    }

}
```

and finally rtype model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Rtype extends Model
{
    
    protected $table = 'r_types';
    protected $casts = [
        'r_date_id' => 'int',
        'num_rooms' => 'int'
    ];

    protected $fillable = [
        'r_date_id',
        'num_rooms',
        'created_by',
        'updated_by'
    ];


    public function rdates(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\RDate','r_date_id','id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that all Reservations have at least one RDate? I think you need to check for null after getting rdates. Try to debug what are you getting from rdates relation in each iteration of foreach loop.

Comment: To add to Umar answer, you can also bypass the null error by add a question mark on the relationship "<p>{{$reservation->rdates?->first()->rtypes?->first()->num_rooms}}</p><br>" to check which is actually is null.

Comment: I think there will be a syntax error with your solution :                          syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)